# What is best regex expression or technique to match IP address in C language

Tags: c, regex

I have requirement to match the IP address as below. Whenever i receive any IP addresses as a input then it should be compared with another static IP address, if it is matched, then it should return success.

E.g:

```
Input can be -> 10.1.101.1 , 10.1.121.2, 10.1.234.4, 10.1.232.5 
Static IP address : 10.1.xxx.1,  10.1.xxx.2, 10.1.xxx,4, 10.1.xxx.5   -> Here 3 octet can be any thing.
```

From the above, first, second and fourth octet only should match. Third octet can be any thing [0-255].

I looking for the efficient way of doing in regex in C language. Could you please throw some ideas.

Comment: Do you have to use a regex?  Would it not be easier just convert the IP addresses to 32-bit integer and just do a comparison either directly or via a bitmask approach?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to literally compare `10.1.101.1` to the actual string `10.1.xxx.1`.  And have `xxx` inferred to be a wildcard field?  Or are you looking for an exact match between an item in the Input list and item in the Static list?

Comment: As for regex, I believe you may [use this](https://ideone.com/bRzUQL).

Comment: @john 517501, You can't use if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it’s available to you, i.e. you’re running on a system that provides it, use the [inet_aton(..](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton)) function to convert your input to bytes, and then do the comparison there.

```
#DEFINE COMPAREMASK  0xFFFF00FF
#DEFINE TEST_ADDR_1  0x0A010001
in_addr addr;

inet_aton(inString, & addr);

if ( (addr.sin_addr&COMPAREMASK) == TEST_ADDR_1) { /* stuff */}
```

(That code is just a sketch, needs the other three comparisons, might have to modify constants for endian type, etc)

Using a real decoder makes your result more robust against all the [weird and wacky ways that people can write internet addresses](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-main-ipaddr-text-rep-00)

Comment: This would work well as a comment, but it's not much of an answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The question was “Best .. technique”.  Do you think a regex can beat it in speed or lines of code?

Comment: Thanks for all your responses.. But i am thinking to use the regex expression here for better performance..